# PHP: python exec command

Tags: php, python

I'm testing with PHP and Python, I`m trying print a text.

test.py:

```
import sys

print "x => " + sys.argv[1] + " y => " + sys.argv[2]
```

When I do:

> sudo python test.py 5 9

The output is:

> x => 5 y => 9

But when I do this in PHP:

```
<?php
exec("sudo python /home/pi/python/test.py 6 3");
?>
```

It shows nothing in the console. Not an error.

[image: console]
I have also tried system() or shell_exec but its not working.

How can this working?

Comment: have you tried `exec("sudo /usr/bin/python /home/pi/python/test.py 6 3");`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that whatever user your PHP/WebServer is running on, does not have access to sudo, nor /home/pi. All in all, I wouldn't use sudo like this and rather set proper permissions for the user that PHP/WebServer is running on to execute said python script.

To solve it:

Put `test.py` in webroot (`/var/www` usually) and remove `sudo` from your php script:

```
<?php
exec("python /var/www/test.py 6 3");
?>
```

You might also need to provide full path to python binary, like this:

```
<?php
exec("/usr/bin/python /var/www/test.py 6 3");
?>
```

To find out where python binary really is stored, you can use command `which` like this:

```
which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I have 2 users: root and pi, I have no idea what the password is from root, but when I login with pi sudo works.

Comment: Yes but I doubt that your webserver (apache?) is running on user PI. It usually is running under separate user (like www-data, or www, or http, depending on distribution). Your webserver probably can't even access /home/pi

Comment: Yes, it runs on Apache, how to give the user www access to /home/pi? Or does the python script in the folder var/www?

Comment: Put the python script in /var/www and remove `sudo`

Comment: I have tried, but its not working too. No errors etc. I think there is something wrong with the premissions.

Comment: I found the error log:  [Errno 13] Permission denied
/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/var/www/test.py':, which python says /usr/bin/python, so thats ok.

Comment: do this: `chown www-data /var/www/test.py`. This will make `www-data` user owner of the file. If that does not work, you can try `chmod 777` just to debug it, but it is not a safe thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
exec("sudo python /home/pi/python/test.py 6 3 2>&1");
?>
```

Comment: There is noting in the console. It is possible that the print is comming into the console or need I to echo the exec?

Answer (score 0):

The `exec()` function returns the last line of the executed command (see [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)). In order to see it on the console, you need to output it:

```
echo exec("sudo python /home/pi/python/test.py 6 3");
```

If you want to see the full output of your executed command, have a look at [`passthru()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php).